# Sender address rejected error while sending emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, smtp, actionmailer

I am developing a ruby on rails application which sends out emails. When I try to send emails from mailer is says `553 : Sender address rejected: not owned by user X`. 
But I try to send an email manually using `Net::SMTP` it goes well. I am kind of stuck for the release. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your mail server is configured to check if the client is allowed to send mail with the supplied sender address. Your application does not authenticate itself as a user who is allowed to use the email address ("x" in your question) as a sender.

See [this forum post](http://www.iredmail.org/forum/topic342-sender-address-rejected-not-owned-by-user.html). Likely when you try it manually you are logging in under a different name than your application.